# Google Sheets Query Function with multiple Cell References and where statements

Tags: sql, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am attempting to Query some Data with multiple conditions and cell references in which the query column C should equal cell reference A2 (Text Data) and the query column f is greater then cell reference B1(Numerical Data).

When I query Just one condition, such as greater then contents in b1, my query works and looks like this :

`=QUERY(DataTable,"Select A,B,C,F where F >"&B1,-1)`

However, when I try to combine the two statements with this query:

`=QUERY(DataTable, "SELECT A,B,C,F WHERE C = '"&A2&"' AND F >= '"&B1, -1)`

I get a #VALUE error. How can I get the query to work with both conditions?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY(DataTable, "SELECT A,B,C,F WHERE C = '"&A2&"' AND F >= "&B1, -1)
```